# HTML: How to halt image loading on link click

Tags: html, lazy-loading, image

I have a page with a few hundred images. If the user clicks a link while the images are loading, the page isn't refreshed until ALL the images are loaded. A savvy user presses ESC and then clicks the link, but I can't expect my users to do that.

Is there a way to get all other actions to take precedence over the image loading? Do I have to go to some javascript lazy-loading and then ruin the site for non-js users?

Example Page http://metaward.com/6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What browser are you using and what operating system? On my machine, Vista with firefox 3 clicking a link before all images load works just fine.

Comment: I ditto this. You shouldn't have to stop the images loading.

Comment: yes it's probably the browser's fault. I bet you are using some distro of linux. Maybe you can post a bug request to the browser's author?

Comment: Interesting. So you think the standard is to keep the image loading at lowest priority? I'm on Vista with FF 3.5. In IE8, it works as I want. If most browsers that is the expected behavior I don't have to change anything.

Comment: so they changed the behavior from Firefox 3 to 3.5? weird. I think that loading images should be a background task. At least that's how i would implement it if i wrote a browser. I guess what you should to is try it with firefox 3 as well and if you see that only 3.5 has this issue, post a bug to let the developers know of the issue.